# Onde usar comparação de objetos, sobrecarregando Equals em projetos DDD com C#

Tags: c#, ddd

Por exemplo tenho esse código que peguei de um exemplo com implementação DDD :

```
 public abstract class Entity {

    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var compareTo = obj as Entity;

        if (ReferenceEquals(this, compareTo)) return true;
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, compareTo)) return false;

        return Id.Equals(compareTo.Id);
    }

    public static bool operator ==(Entity a, Entity b)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(a, null) && ReferenceEquals(b, null))
            return true;

        if (ReferenceEquals(a, null) || ReferenceEquals(b, null))
            return false;

        return a.Equals(b);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(Entity a, Entity b)
    {
        return !(a == b);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (GetType().GetHashCode() * 907) + Id.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return GetType().Name + " [Id=" + Id + "]";
    }
```

}

E logo têm esse método :

```
  public Task<bool> Handle(UpdateCustomerCommand message, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        if (!message.IsValid())
        {
            NotifyValidationErrors(message);
            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }

        var customer = new Customer(message.Id, message.Name, message.Email, message.BirthDate);
        var existingCustomer = _customerRepository.GetByEmail(customer.Email);

        if (existingCustomer != null && existingCustomer.Id != customer.Id)
        {
            if (!existingCustomer.Equals(customer)) //Aqui está usando a comparação de Objetos
            {
                Bus.RaiseEvent(new DomainNotification(message.MessageType,"The customer e-mail has already been taken."));
                return Task.FromResult(false);
            }
        }

        _customerRepository.Update(customer);

        if (Commit())
        {
            Bus.RaiseEvent(new CustomerUpdatedEvent(customer.Id, customer.Name, customer.Email, customer.BirthDate));
        }

        return Task.FromResult(true);
   }
```

Por mais que tenha esse exemplo não entendi o porquê ou o que exatamente ele faz aqui para usar o !existingCustomer.Equals(customer), sendo que  existingCustomer.Id != customer.Id já não faria isso.

```
        var customer = new Customer(message.Id, message.Name, message.Email, message.BirthDate);
        var existingCustomer = _customerRepository.GetByEmail(customer.Email);

        if (existingCustomer != null && existingCustomer.Id != customer.Id)
        {
            if (!existingCustomer.Equals(customer)) //Aqui está usando a comparação de Objetos
            {
                Bus.RaiseEvent(new DomainNotification(message.MessageType,"The customer e-mail has already been taken."));
                return Task.FromResult(false);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pela linha Bus.RaiseEvent é possível deduzir que Equals compara o email e dispara um evento de domínio indicando que a ação não é possível porque o e-mail já está em uso.